# Which Intelligent query processing features are available in the Enterprise Edition only?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019, sql-server-2022

Many features have been released starting from SQL Server 2017 to SQL Server 2022 as part of the 'Intelligent query processing' family. Which ones are Enterprise only, and which are available in the Standard Edition of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

Reference: [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2022?view=sql-server-ver16)

**Enterprise Edition Only:**

- Intelligent Database: Batch mode adaptive joins
- Intelligent Database: Batch mode memory grant feedback
- Intelligent Database: row mode memory grant feedback
- Intelligent Database: memory grant feedback persistence and percentile
- Intelligent Database: cardinality estimate feedback
- Intelligent Database: degree of parallelism feedback
- Intelligent Database: batch mode for row store

**Available in All Editions:**

- Intelligent Database: Interleaved execution for multi-statement table valued functions
- Intelligent Database: approximate count distinct
- Intelligent Database: approximate percentile
- Intelligent Database: scalar UDF inlining
- Intelligent Database: parameter sensitive plan optimization
- Intelligent Database: optimized plan forcing

Comment: Why do some have “Intelligent Database:” and others not?

Comment: Don't know.  That is how it is defined in the reference page. Which is not same as learn website about IQP features.  I will inquire about this via github.

Comment: @ErikDarling answer update. Submitted a PR and was merged. All IQP features are preceded with the same wording on learn website.